# Eclipse file URL from own bundle

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

this is not really a problem I have, but more a question about good practice.

I want to resolve a URL of a File of my eclipse plugin, but there are many ways which work. I could not find anything about which one should be preferred.

First of all: how should I obtain my bundle? Through the Activator or the Platform?

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("my.bundle.id");
```

or

```
Bundle bundle = Activator.getDefault().getBundle();
```

The other question is how to get the url. Either with

```
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("folder/file.txt"), null);
```

or

```
URL url = bundle.getEntry("folder/file.txt");
```

All of this works, but which way is the best? Does it even make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't make any difference (actually `FileLocator` uses `bundle.getEntry`). The advantage is of using `bundle.getEntry` is that you don't have a dependency to an eclipse-bundle; I don't know if that fact is relevant for you.

I'm always using the `FileLocator` method in RCPs but using the `openStream` method to read the contents of files within bundles.

Comment: Thanks Tom, any advice about the first question, resolving of the bundle?

Comment: I'd prefer `Platform.getBundle` since it uses the PackageAdmin service (an OSGi framework service). It's also a way which will work always (also if you have no Activator or the bundle is not started)